# adding object to list overwrite some results

Tags: java, list, overwrite

I added objects to list however there was overriding problem.How can solve this? I sended 3 value in transactionIdList in my main method.
these three value to send below method, i want to add all results return. However there is only two results return with bsList which are in the `( basvuru != null && !basvuru.isEmpty()))` state.

```
     List<ApplicationResult> bsList = new ArrayList();
     Application bsDB = new Application();

     for (int i = 0; i < transactionIdList.size(); i++) {
        List basvuru = session.createQuery("from Application as bsvr where bsvr.transactionId = :var1").setParameter("var1", transactionIdList.get(i)).list();
        if (basvuru == null) {
           ApplicationResult bss = new ApplicationResult();
           bss.setTransactionId(transactionIdList.get(i));
           bss.setBasvuruDurum("no value");
           bsList.add(bss);
        } else if (basvuru != null && !basvuru.isEmpty()){
           ApplicationResult bs = new ApplicationResult();
           bsDB = (Application) basvuru.get(0);
           bs.setTransactionId(bsDB.getTransactionId());
           bs.setBasvuruDurum(bsDB.getDurum());
           bsList.add(bs); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: so that means you might not have data in database. Did you checked that? Objects added in a list never gets overwritten (unless you use api other than say add)

Comment: Your statements in the question doesn't make sense. What is overriding problem? Also, you are adding `bs` to `bsList` based on two flow conditions (if and else if) - what if your `bs` value is not satisfied using those two? You don't seem to be adding 'bs' value after that - isn't that why you get two results in `bsList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only explanation is that `session.createQuery()` returns one `List` that is not `null`, but is empty.

Comment: yes, nevertheless thats the solution.It Works sorry about this stupid one.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that basvruru at some time is not null but an empty list. In this case, nothing is added to the bsList.

You probably want to update the if clause to `basvuru == null || basvuru.isEmpty()`, and just use and else.

Comment: i used else however it gave   rangeCheck array or something like this exception at the  bsDB = (Application) basvuru.get(0); line .

Comment: calling get(int) on an empty list will always thrown an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. Your second block of code should only run if the list is not null, and also not empty.

Answer (score 0):

in `List` implementation values never get overridden. You must have some other issue. could be `basvuru` is not `null`